# Rails' link_to method: :delete not recognized on ipad. Sends GET request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ipad

There are many answers to similar questions that say to add

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

to the application.js file. I already have these. My links work perfectly on desktop, however on the iPad, even though the link has the data-method="delete", the server still treats it as a GET request.

What is the fix to make this work on an ipad?

Here is my code:

`<%= link_to "/things/#{thing.id}", :class => 'cool-thing',
         :method => :delete do %>
     <img src=awesome.png>
 <% end %>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've run into a couple (albeit very edge-case) situations where browser support for Rails' UJS is very fragile. You could likely dig into this issue and come out with a clean solution, but it might be more time-effective to simply add a GET version to the routes if support for this link is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if this question will attract any more answers, but indeed what you said is a good quick and dirty fix.